# What LEGO piece is this?

Tags: part-identification

Could anyone identify this piece?

[image: Photo of piece of to identify]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  This part is mostly used for tracked vehicles or conveyor belts in official sets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome. This is [57518 Technic, Link Tread Wide with Two Pin Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57518&name=Technic,%20Link%20Tread%20Wide%20with%20Two%20Pin%20Holes&category=%5BTechnic,%20Link%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]